# how to convert list with tuples and dictionaries to dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have a list like below:

```
    [(u'profileDetails', {u'customerCategory': {u'masterCode': u'PRECAT1'},
 u'identificationDetails': {u'identificationDetail':
            [{u'idType': {u'masterCode': u'PASS'}}, 
            {u'idType': {u'masterCode': u'REGFORM'}}]}, 
u'customerSubCategory': {u'masterCode': u'PRESCAT1'}}), 
    (u'_id', u'58872e99321a0c8633291b3f')]
```

I want to convert this as below:

```
    {"profileDetails":{"customerCategory":{"masterCode":"PRECAT1"},
"identificationDetails":{"identificationDetail":
     [{"idType":{"masterCode":"PASS"}},
     {"idType":{"masterCode":"REGFORM"}}]},
"customerSubCategory":{"masterCode":"PRESCAT1"}},
"_id": "58872e99321a0c8633291b3f"}
```

I understood the result above has tuples, lists and dictionaries and all the data in unicode format.

I need to convert unicode to string and tuples and list to dictionary. How can I achieve this in Python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a dict comprehension:

```
In [2]: lst = [(u'profileDetails', {u'customerCategory': {u'masterCode': u'PRECAT1'}, u'identificationDetails': {u'identificationDetail': [{u'idType': {u'masterCode': u'PASS'}}, {u'idType': {u'masterCode': u'REGFORM'}}]}, u'customerSubCategory': {u'masterCode': u'PRESCAT1'}}), 
   ...: (u'_id', '58872e99321a0c8633291b3f')]

In [3]: {i: j for i, j in lst}
Out[3]: 
{'_id': '58872e99321a0c8633291b3f',
 'profileDetails': {'customerCategory': {'masterCode': 'PRECAT1'},
  'customerSubCategory': {'masterCode': 'PRESCAT1'},
  'identificationDetails': {'identificationDetail': [{'idType': {'masterCode': 'PASS'}},
    {'idType': {'masterCode': 'REGFORM'}}]}}}
```

Note that since I didn't have the `ObjectId` I replaced it with its string argument.

If your list is contain tuples with length 1 or more than 2, you can use a try-except in order to handle the `ValueError`:

```
def dict_creator(my_list):
    for tup in my_list:
        try:
            key, value = tup
        except ValueError:
            # do what you want with tup
        else:
            yield key, value

final_dict = dict(dict_creator(my_list))
```

Or if you just want to ignore those tuples you can check the length through the dict comprehension:

```
{tup[0]: tup[1] for tup in lst if len(tup) == 2}
```

In case you have a string of tuple you can use `ast.literal_eval` in order to convert the string to tuple object.

Comment: `{i: j for i, j in lst}` is just `dict(lst)`

Comment: hi chris and kasramvd, thanks for your reply, in my case it is not working , when i tried the both solutions `{i: j for i, j in lst}` or `dict(lst)`, i am getting the error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi Maybe some of the tuples are not contain 2 elements (they're contain 1 element instead.)

Comment: hi kasramvd, no it has two elements, when i declare the input as variable and try, it is working fine, but if i take the same input as argument to the method and inside method try to convert to dictionary then that error is coming

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi So just handle the exceptions as in update is shown.

Comment: Hi Kasramvd, i understood the problem, i defined a function as `def convert_data(data): <br> print dict(data)` the argument coming to the function is a `String` and it has the data in the form of `tuple`, is because of this causing the problem? because when directly declare the variable as `data= [(u'profileDetails',{ u'customerCategory': {u'masterCode': u'PRECAT1'}})]` and try to convert `print dict(data)` then it is working fine.  can u help how to convert data type of Variable from String to tuple, that solves the problem  i think, in case of function

Comment: @SaradaAkurathi I don't completely got that what you mean by * the argument coming to the function is a String and it has the data in the form of tuple* if you have a string of tuple you may need to consider using `ast.literal_eval` in order to convert the string to a python object.

Comment: This worked for me, Thanks a lot for your suggestion. I used now this way `dict(ast.literal_eval(jsondata))` and got the result. Can you update the answer, i will accept the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just type-cast the list of tuples to `dict` as:

```
>>> dict(my_list)
```

which will return:

```
{'_id': '58872e99321a0c8633291b3f', 
 'profileDetails': {
      'customerSubCategory': {'masterCode': 'PRESCAT1'}, 
      'identificationDetails': {'identificationDetail': [
          {'idType': {'masterCode': 'PASS'}}, 
          {'idType': {'masterCode': 'REGFORM'}}
      ]}, 
  'customerCategory': {'masterCode': 'PRECAT1'}}
 }
```

Here, `my_list` is the list of tuples mentioned in the question.

When list of tuples (or list) in the form `[(x1, y1), (x2, y2)]` is type-casted to `dict`, python's interpreter creates a dict object of the format `{x1: y1, x2: y2}` i.e. all the elements at the 0th index of the tuple becomes *key* and the elements at the index 1 becomes *value* to the resultant dict.

Comment: Hi moinuddin, Thanks for reply, This solution worked for me when i took the input into a variable, means i declared the input as `jsondata = [(u'profileDetails',{ u'customerCategory': {u'masterCode': u'PRECAT1'}})]` and converted this as `print dict(jsondata)`  but not working when taking as argument to the function. can you help me, what went wrong

Comment: Hi moinuddin, my code is like below:   `def convert_to_dict(data):    <br>    print dict(data)   <br>`  then i am getting the error `ValueError: dictionary update sequence element #0 has length 1; 2 is required`. Can you help me what went wrong.